# Substituting meyer lemons for sour oranges

Tags: substitutions, citrus

Many Cuban recipes use the juice of sour oranges as an ingredient, [such as mojo sauce](https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2011/06/sauced-mojo-sauce-condiments-recipe.html).  Unfortunately, sour oranges are hard to find in the Western USA.

The standard substitutions offered include, depending on the cookbook:

- a 1:1 ratio of sweet orange and lemon juice
- a 1:2 ratio of sweet orange and lemon juice
- a 2:1 ratio of sweet orange and lime juice
- various combinations of orange juice and vinegar

It occured to me today that Meyer lemons are a cross between mandarin oranges and lemons, and as such might have a flavor close to sour oranges.  Questions:

1. Are Meyer lemons actually close in flavor to sour oranges?
2. What substitution ratio should I use for meyer lemon juice (plus possibly sweet orange and/or lime juice) to sour orange juice?

Looking for answers with documentation and/or direct experience here, please, rather than guesses.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Interesting idea.  I use Meyer lemons regularly, but wouldn't have thought to substitute them directly for sour oranges.  My usual substitution would be more your 2:1 ratio of sweet orange and lime juice (certainly not vinegar, eeeck!).  Unless your Meyer lemons are exceptionally sweet, I'd add a bit of sweet orange juice to them.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Meyer lemons in cooking and found that they just don’t have sufficient flavor to justify using Meyers. The end product came out neither sweet nor lemony. There was a lack of flavor.

Comment: Welcome! This is useful to know about Meyer lemons. How does this compare to a bitter orange, though? Is it similar enough to be a substitute?

Comment: Well, this not really knowing anything about them :-).  Sounds like poor Anne only had some supermarket-shriveled version, rather than the real thing which is indeed sweet but intensely lemony...